# MarkLogic get data from collection

Tags: java, xml, collections, marklogic

Is it possible to get data from MarkLogic xml database, but using MarkLogic API for java?
I have read documentation, but it only shows how to add a xml to collection or to delete it, doesn't show how to get all xml documents from one selected collection?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it will do the job

https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/index.html?com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html

> StructuredQueryBuilder.CollectionConstraintQuery  collectionConstraint(String constraintName, String... uris)
>   Matches documents belonging to at least one of the criteria collections with the specified constraint.

Comment: Tnx i dont know how i didnt see that.